# deleter decorator using Property in Python

Tags: python, properties, decorator

I'm playing around with property in Python and I was wondering how this @propertyName.deleter decorator works. I'm probably missing something, I could not find clear answers by Google.

What I would like to achieve is when this **deleter** behavior is called, I can trigger other actions (e.g: using my 3d application SDK).

For now just a simple print() doesn't seem to get triggered.

Is **deleter** fired when I delete the property using **del(instance.property)** ?

Otherwise, how can I achieve this?

```
class M():

    def __init__(self):
        self._m = None

    @property
    def mmm(self):
        return self._m

    @mmm.setter
    def mmm(self, val):
        self._m = val

    @mmm.deleter
    def mmm(self):
        print('deleting') # Not printing
        del(self._m)




if __name__ == '__main__':

    i = M()
    i.mmm = 150
    print(i.mmm)
    del(i.mmm)
    print(i.mmm)
```

Thank you very much (:

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Make M a new-style class:

```
class M(object):
```

See http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2.3/descrintro/#property:

> **Properties do not work for classic
>   classes**, but you don't get a clear
>   error when you try this. Your get
>   method will be called, so it appears
>   to work, but upon attribute
>   assignment, a classic class instance
>   will simply set the value in its
>   **dict** without calling the property's set method, and after that,
>   the property's get method won't be
>   called either. (You could override
>   **setattr** to fix this, but it would be prohibitively expensive.)

Answer (score 9):

In Python 3 you WOULD see the `print`'s result -- and then an AttributeError for the last print (because `_m` has disappeared).  You may be using Python 2.6, in which case you need to change the `class` clause to `class M(object):` to make `M` new-style, and then you'll get the same behavior as in Python 3.